# pyarrow causes python to crash errors on parquet.dll

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

I have a script which fetches data, and stores the data in Pandas dataframe.

I make 3 aggregations of data, MEAN/STDEV/MAX, each of which are converted to an arrow table and saved on the disk as a parquet file.

I use pyarrow for converting a Pandas Frame to a Arrow Table. ( I cannot create a pyarrow tag, since I need more point apparently)

This code works just fine for 100-500 records, but errors out for bigger volume. I also know this code works because another developer is using the same code on a mirrored machine ( in terms of hardware ) and it works.
The order of the dataset I am trying to save is millions.

The code errors out @ line  pq.write_table(arrowTable, filePath).

Here is the code:

```
arrowTable = pa.Table.from_pandas(self.grpByMeanDS2)

begintime = datetime.now()
begintime_str = begintime.strftime("%Y%m%d%I%M%S")      

filePath = SaveFileLoc + "\\Raw\\" + agg + "Data" + begintime_str + ".parq"

print('Begin Saving File')
pq.write_table(arrowTable, filePath)
print('Done Saving File')

print('Appending FilePath to List')
self.listspDF.append(filePath)
print('Done Appending FilePath to List')
```

Python crashes and throws a "python has to close error".

### Following is the detailed error:

Problem Event Name:                        APPCRASH
  Application Name:                           python.exe
  Application Version:                        3.5.2150.1013
  Application Timestamp:                  577be340
  Fault Module Name:                        parquet.dll
  Fault Module Version:                     0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:               59403662
  Exception Code:                               c0000005
  Exception Offset:                              000000000005f990
  OS Version:                                       6.3.9600.2.0.0.400.8
  Locale ID:                                          1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

---

I have tried updating Python and pyarrow, with no luck.

Following is the version of python:

```
import sys

print (sys.version)
3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Following are results of pip freeze:

```
alabaster==0.7.9
anaconda-clean==1.0
anaconda-client==1.5.1
anaconda-navigator==1.3.1
argcomplete==1.0.0
astroid==1.4.7
astropy==2.0
Babel==2.3.4
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
beautifulsoup4==4.5.1
bitarray==0.8.1
blaze==0.10.1
bokeh==0.12.2
boto==2.42.0
Bottleneck==1.2.1
cffi==1.7.0
chest==0.2.3
click==6.6
cloudpickle==0.2.1
clyent==1.2.2
colorama==0.3.7
comtypes==1.1.2
conda==4.3.22
conda-build==2.0.2
configobj==5.0.6
contextlib2==0.5.3
cryptography==1.5
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.24.1
cytoolz==0.8.0
dask==0.11.0
datashape==0.5.2
decorator==4.0.10
dill==0.2.5
docutils==0.12
dynd===c328ab7
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
fastcache==1.0.2
filelock==2.0.6
Flask==0.11.1
Flask-Cors==2.1.2
gevent==1.1.2
greenlet==0.4.10
h5py==2.7.0
HeapDict==1.0.0
idna==2.1
imageio==2.2.0
imagesize==0.7.1
ipykernel==4.5.0
ipython==5.1.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
ipywidgets==5.2.2
itsdangerous==0.24
jdcal==1.2
jedi==0.9.0
Jinja2==2.8
jsonschema==2.5.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==4.4.0
jupyter-console==5.0.0
jupyter-core==4.2.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.2.1
llvmlite==0.19.0
locket==0.2.0
lxml==3.6.4
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==2.0.2
menuinst==1.4.1
mistune==0.7.3
mpmath==0.19
multipledispatch==0.4.8
nb-anacondacloud==1.2.0
nb-conda==2.0.0
nb-conda-kernels==2.0.0
nbconvert==4.2.0
nbformat==4.1.0
nbpresent==3.0.2
networkx==1.11
nltk==3.2.1
nose==1.3.7
notebook==4.2.3
numba==0.34.0
numexpr==2.6.2
numpy==1.13.1
odo==0.5.0
openpyxl==2.3.2
pandas==0.20.2
partd==0.3.6
path.py==0.0.0
pathlib2==2.1.0
patsy==0.4.1
pep8==1.7.0
pickleshare==0.7.4
Pillow==3.3.1
pkginfo==1.3.2
ply==3.9
prompt-toolkit==1.0.3
psutil==4.3.1
py==1.4.31
py4j==0.10.4
pyarrow==0.4.1
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycosat==0.6.1
pycparser==2.14
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0
pyflakes==1.3.0
Pygments==2.1.3
pyidealdata==0.7.0
pylint==1.5.4
pyodbc==4.0.17
pyOpenSSL==16.2.0
pyparsing==2.1.4
pyspark==2.1.0+hadoop2.7
pytest==2.9.2
python-dateutil==2.5.3
pytz==2016.6.1
PyUber==1.4.4
PyWavelets==0.5.2
pywin32==220
PyYAML==3.12
pyzmq==15.4.0
QtAwesome==0.3.3
qtconsole==4.2.1
QtPy==1.1.2
requests==2.14.2
rope-py3k==0.9.4.post1
ruamel-yaml===-VERSION
scikit-image==0.13.0
scikit-learn==0.18.2
scipy==0.19.1
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
sockjs-tornado==1.0.3
sphinx==1.4.6
spyder==3.0.0
SQLAlchemy==1.0.13
statsmodels==0.8.0
sympy==1.0
tables==3.2.2
toolz==0.8.0
tornado==4.4.1
traitlets==4.3.0
unicodecsv==0.14.1
wcwidth==0.1.7
Werkzeug==0.11.11
widgetsnbextension==1.2.6
win-unicode-console==0.5
wrapt==1.10.6
xlrd==1.0.0
XlsxWriter==0.9.3
xlwings==0.10.0
xlwt==1.1.2
```

I was wondering if someone could shed light why pyarrow would not work on a certain machine ?

Thanks,
Adu

Answer (score 0):

Any segfault or other crash should be treated as a bug, so let's address on the Apache Arrow JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1247